# Break function from nested function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I try to break a function from a nested function, like a interceptor. An example is worth a thousand words:

```
function main (arg: number): string {
   interceptor(arg);

   return "normal return";
}

function interceptor (arg: number) {
   if(arg === 2) return "return from interceptor function"; // Here return this value by main()
}

main(1); // "normal return"
main(2); // "return from interceptor function"
```

I know this can be done with try/catch statements by a "throw", but I don't want to modify the main function to do it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
function main (arg: number): string {
   interceptor(arg);
   return "normal return";
}
```

If `main` cannot be modified, the only way to stop `normal return` from being returned is to throw an error. There is no other way.

If you *can* modify `main`, the way to do it would be for `interceptor` to return a value, and to check and return it if it exists.

```
function main (arg: number): string {
   return interceptor(arg) || "normal return";
}
```